# InfluxDB: Collectd parse error: invalid data service=collectd

Tags: python, influxdb, collectd, influxdb-python

We have a test environment with Collectd and InfluxDB on the same machine.
Everything works fine until we add a Python Collectd plugin.
When a Python plugin is dispatching values we get following error log from InfluxDB:

```
Jan 26 10:00:24 influxdb influxd: [I] 2017-01-26T09:00:24Z Collectd parse error: invalid data service=collect
```

---

**Our setup:** 
Collectd 5.6 
InfluxDB 1.2.

Collectd Python plugin config:

```
<LoadPlugin python>
  Globals true
</LoadPlugin>

<Plugin python>
  ModulePath "/opt/python-collectd"
  LogTraces true
  Interactive false
  Import "randomtest"
</Plugin>
```

Collectd network config:

```
LoadPlugin network

<Plugin network>
        Server "localhost" "25826"
</Plugin>
```

Source of "randomtest"

```
import collectd
import random    

def configer(confObj):
    collectd.info('config called')

def init_fun():
    collectd.info('init called')

def reader(input_data=None):
        value = collectd.Values()
        value.plugin = 'test_plugin'
        value.host = 'test-host'
        value.interval = 10
        value.type = 'absolute'
        value.type_instance = 'test'
        value.values = [random.randint(0,10)]
        value.dispatch()    

collectd.register_config(configer)
collectd.register_init(init_fun)
collectd.register_read(reader)
```

InfluxDB collectd config:

```
 [[collectd]]
   enabled = true
   bind-address = ":25826"
   database = "collectd"
   retention-policy = ""
   typesdb = "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"

  # These next lines control how batching works. You should have this enabled
  # otherwise you could get dropped metrics or poor performance. Batching
  # will buffer points in memory if you have many coming in.

  # Flush if this many points get buffered
   batch-size = 5000

  # Number of batches that may be pending in memory
   batch-pending = 10

  # Flush at least this often even if we haven't hit buffer limit
   batch-timeout = "10s"

  # UDP Read buffer size, 0 means OS default. UDP listener will fail if set above OS max.
   read-buffer = 0
```

---

Just to clarify:
If i comment Import "randomtest" out in the Collectd python config everything seems to work fine again. 
We also looked at tcpdumps but we couldn't notice a difference between Python Collectd plugins and other Collectd plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue and have opened an issue on GitHub, but with the curl_xml and snmp plugins.

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8184

Downgrading InfluxDB to 1.1.1 appears to restore functionality.